# Computing the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(t^2-1)\delta(t)\:dt$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Have I solved this problem correctly?

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(t^2-1\right)\delta\left(t\right)\:dt&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^2\delta\left(t\right)\:dt-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(t\right)\:dt\tag{1} \\
&=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^2\delta\left(t\right)\:dt-1\tag{2} \\
&=0-1=\boxed{-1.}\tag{3}
\end{align}

Such that $\delta\left(t\right)$ is the dirac-delta function.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see the point in splitting up the integral, we can just evaluate $t^2-1$ at $t=0$ directly no?

Comment: +1 You did fine but you don't need to split the integral as @anon already pointed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the property

$$  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta(t)\, dt = f(0) $$
for $f(t)=t^2-1$ you have
$$  \int_{-\infty}^\infty (t^2-1)\delta(t)\, dt = -1. $$